# My JS is never called. Why? I want to change input value in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a piece of code more or less like the one below.

```
    <FORM id=form1 name="form1" autocomplete="off" method=post action="submit.php" onsubmit="change_value();">
    <div width="100%" class="s-dwa-login-header">Test</div>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:30%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <div class="s-dwa-login-table-container">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="s-dwa-login-table s-dwa-login-font" role="presentation">
                    <tr><td></td><td valign="top" colspan="3"></td></tr>
                <tr>
            <td width="40px"></td>
            <td colspan="3" class="s-dwa-login-heading">Welcome to Test</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td width="40px"></td>
            <td colspan="3" class="s-dwa-login-heading">My Test</td></tr>
                  <tr>
            <td></td>
              <td align="left" colspan="3" class="s-dwa-error-text"><div id="errormsg"></div></td>
                </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;" valign="middle" width="15%"><label for="user_name">User name: </label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td align="left" width="50%" colspan="2">
<input name="UsernameForm" value="" size=20 maxlength=50 id='user_name' tabindex='10' aria-required='true' class="s-dwa-login-input" style="width:100%"></td>
            <td></td>
                </tr>
                        <tr><td></td></tr>
                        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;" valign="middle" width="15%"><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td align="left" width="50%" colspan="2">
<input name="PasswordForm" value="" type="password" onclick="javascript:change_valua()" size=20 maxlength=50 id='password' autocomplete='off' tabindex='20' aria-required='true' class="s-dwa-login-input" style="width:100%"></td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px"</td>
```

This code is inside `<body>`. I want for example to always change the user input password to "MyTestPassword" - I know it makes no sense, but is just to explain.

I tried:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    var inp = document.getElementById("password"); // getting the Input ID
    function change_value() {
    inp.value = 'Your Value'; // <-- value
    }

    var inx = document.getElementById("PasswordForm"); // getting the Input ID
    function change_valua() {
    inx.value = 'Your Value'; // <-- value
    }

   function SubmitForm()
   {

   document.form1.password.value = 'qazwsxedcrfv';
   document.form1.PasswordForm.value = 'qazwsxedcrfv';
   return true;

  }

  function clkLgn()
  {

  document.form1.password.value = 'qazwsxedcrfv';
  document.form1.PasswordForm.value = 'qazwsxedcrfv';
  return true;

 }
 </script>
```

I tried insert this code everywhere, inside `<body>`, inside `<head>`, but it never works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your console (hit F12) for errors?

Comment: Every modern browser has developer tools for debugging JavaScript. Use them! You are in a much position to debug the code and find issue than we are (because we don't have the full picture).

Comment: Where exactly is your code ? _everywhere, inside , inside_ is not so clear...

Comment: Where are yours inputs inside your code? I cant find any in your source.

Show me your example on https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single error in your code, the whole thing will be broken (not run)

Test your code:

(1) Press F12 (Google Chrome) and click on Console tab. Refresh page (F5) and see if any errors show up (in red)

(2) Reduce the javascript until it works. Begin with just:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('working')
</script>
```

Gradually add-in your javascript until you find the bit that breaks it.

---

The javascript you display in your question can be placed virtually anywhere within the `<head>` or `<body>` of the page, although placement at the very bottom *immediately before the `</body></html>` tags is efficient.

Comment: Thanks all replies. Weird, neither a simple alert() is working, the code is really never executed. I have no idea what could be. I see nothing wrong pressing F12 :(

Comment: Edit your question and add the full code for your web page - from `<DOCTYPE>` to `</html>` so we can see if you've left unclosed tags that interfere with the js.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure about the full code, use a simpliest test to check with less html, scripts, etc. As follow, you can see the password value changing when the submit event is triggered :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.getElementById("MyLoginForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        document.getElementById("password").value = "MyTestPassword";
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<form id="MyLoginForm" name="form1" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="">
    <input id="login" type="text" />
    <input id="password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="GoGogO" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't forget to delete `event.preventDefault();` and `return false` in your own codes. They are only used for the demo.

Comment: Dark seeds you rock! It solved my issue. Thanks.

BTW, what document do you advise me to read and understand this code properly?

Comment: You have a lot of web resources available here and there. But i found this website very useful and complete : http://eloquentjavascript.net enjoy ^_^